# It's no more glaring than in the early hours of a developing story

Tags: phrase-meaning, negation, comparatives

The following is an excerpt from The Japan Times of June 22. What does "It's no more glaring than in the early hours of a developing story" mean?

> The spread of misinformation ‒ "fake news" if that's more your speed ‒ has long been an issue, but social media has accelerated it significantly. It's no more glaring than in the early hours of a developing story, where facts are scarce but the Twitter timeline moves at a rapid pace.

Comment: 'It is never more flagrant than ...'.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, *glaring* means stark, dramatic, obvious, conspicuous with the connotation of being something bad or undesirable.

According to [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glaring), **glaring**: obtrusively and often painfully obvious, as in *a glaring error*

So, what the author is trying to say is that when a story is first developing, there are not many available facts, and the spread of misinformation is most dramatic at that point.

Answer (score -1):

**no more than**  [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/no-more-than)

> used for saying that a particular situation or result seems
>   appropriate or normal

As used in the sentence you cited, it can be confusing, implying possible normality.

Whereas:

> It's **most glaring** in the early hours of a developing story, where
>   facts are scarce but the Twitter timeline moves at a rapid pace.

leaves no question.